# Предуприждение при загрузке аппа в стор Unrecognized Locale

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, локализация

После загрузке приложения в стор выдает предупреждение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел лишь один пример решения подобного, но как применить в своем случае не могу разобраться. Localizable.strings(Spanish... использую для всех доступных стран. Но предупреждение выдает, как видно из скрина, только на две страны. Нашел лишь один пример подобной ситуации https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52739742/warning-itms-90176-unrecognized-locale-base-lproj
но применить на свой случай не разберусь как и что это вообще за проблема

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: «Аппа в стор» — закрыл после этого страницу сразу.

Answer (score 3):

Идем по вашей [ссылке](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html) и видим, что эппл использует стандарт `ISO 3166-1`, далее смотрим список регионов для Испании - и видим, что указанные в тексте локали не являются [принятыми локалями](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:ES#Special_territories), отсюда и ошибка.

В той же статье указаны и действующие коды для указанных территорий. Для Сеуты это `ES-CE`, для Мелильи это `ES-ML`, для Канарских островов `ES-CN`

> The following two areas not covered by European Union Customs
>   arrangements are also exceptionally reserved ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 codes
>   on the request of the World Customs Organization:
>
> ```
> EA Ceuta, Melilla
> IC Canary Islands
> ```
>
> **However, these codes do not correspond in any way to the ISO 3166-2
>   codes of the territories.**

**Дополнение**

Странная ситуация, посмотрел доступные локализации в икскоде, и там как раз предлагаются локализации, для которых у вас выдается предупреждение, предложенных мной локализаций нет, если что дополню ответ, пока что предложенное мной решение не работает

**Дополнение 2**

[Тут](https://gist.github.com/xta/6e9b63db1fa662bb3910b680f9ebd458) нашелся список и код вывода локалей на аойс, попробуйте у себя вывести, будут ли там указанные локали

```
import UIKit

print("localeIdentifier, Description")

let identifiers: NSArray = NSLocale.availableLocaleIdentifiers as NSArray
let locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")

identifiers.forEach {
    let name = locale.displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.identifier, value: $0)!
    print("\($0),\"\(name)\"")
}
```

Comment: Теперь понял суть, спасибо! А как исправить эти коды в проекте?

Comment: @ArturSkachkov как минимум исправить названия соответствующих директорий  `lproj`, подробнее сказать не могу, нет икскода под рукой

Comment: меняю префиксы у папки es-IC.lproj на es-CN.lproj и сразу выдает ошибку, скрин добавил в вопрос

Comment: @ArturSkachkov см дополнение

Comment: @ArturSkachkov см еще одно дополнение, у вас какая версия икскода и свифта и с помощью чего вы заливаете билд (application loader? какой версии?)

Comment: xcode-11.3, swift 5, загружаю из xcode через архивацию.

Comment: добавил код, выводит локали и es_IC,"Spanish (Canary Islands)", и es_EA,"Spanish (Ceuta & Melilla)"

Comment: @ArturSkachkov мда больше гипотез пока нет